# gpfs monitoring service can not be found

Tags: ibm

I am trying to run the command `mmhealth node show` as root on a Linux box.  It returns the following:

```
 Error:  The monitoring service is down and does not respond, please  restart it.
```

I have no idea what service that is.  Does anyone know?

Comment: Have you tried using any search engines or documentation yet?

Comment: Yes.  looked https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/STXKQY_4.2.3/com.ibm.spectrum.scale.v4r23.doc/bl1adm_mmhealth.htm#reference_ylx_2fy_qt and https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/STXKQY_4.2.3/com.ibm.spectrum.scale.v4r23.doc/bl1adv_intro_mmhealth.htm#reference_bl1adv_intro_mmhealth.  The second link is supposed to list pre reqs, but doesn't say anything about a  service.